# Load array of bit-field as ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, data-structures, memory-alignment, bit-fields

i'm developing scientific measurement device interface. I need to load data (received from socket) as numpy array.

Data is 8960 bytes buffer with 5120 14-bit integer values. So, what is the bes way to load it ?
I've tried using ctypes:

```
class PackedValue(ct.BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [("v", ct.c_uint16, 14)]

DataArray = PackedValue * 10

values = DataArray.from_buffer_copy(data)
```

But values is not loaded properly due to array aligning. And then - how to transform this to numpy array because calling

```
nda_values = np.ctypeslib.as_array(values)
```

rases following exception:

```
AttributeError: 'PackedValue' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'
```

So, how to load received data into numpy ndarray with dtype=int16 ?
Or there is faster way to load data without using ctypes ?

Comment: It would help if you show the actual format of the data.  Can you print values and print type(values)?

Comment: Data just received from udp socket - it's simply udp packet payload bytes, type is str in python2.7.

Comment: I wish I had an answer for you, but I'm not very familiar with ctypes. I think this [article](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/05/05/introduction-to-the-python-buffer-protocol/) may be insightful for you though. Good luck!

Comment: `np.ctypeslib.as_array(values)` is just a worse way of spelling `np.asarray(values)`. Both now work in numpy, but only as a result of a bug in ctypes. If you add a second bitfield, numpy now raises `TypeError: ctypes bitfields have no dtype equivalent`